# how to logout with django-social-auth?

Tags: django-socialauth

I'm planning to integrate facebook and google login into my site. 
How do I logout of facebook or google session ?

I tried to use the view below -

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

After logout (using the above view), I'm still able to login (without password) into facebook/google from another browser tab.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to logout or disconnect the account.